# How can I reset the Hot Corners Icon and and make the Top Bar opaque?

Tags: fedora, gnome, theme

[image]

Broke some theming for Fedora Workstation 39. I don't like that Apple icon in the top left and the fact that the Top Bar is transparent? How can I change it back?

I tried:

Resetting Tweaks
dconf reset -f /
Deleting the .themes file